# "error: Unexpected error" during maven build with Android Anotations

Tags: android, maven, android-annotations

I have problem with building project with android anotations (v.2.6) using maven, with eclipse all works just fine. Here is some project and error details:

build configuration snippet from pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
```

and here is output after executing `mvn clean install` on parent project:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) @ native-container framework ---
[INFO] Compiling 102 source files to   /Users/vitaliyzasadnyy/Development/repository/androidcontainer/native-container-   android/native-container-framework/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: Unexpected error. Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]     at com.googlecode.androidannotations.internal.codemodel.JCodeModel.ref(JCodeModel.java:372)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.processing.EBeansHolder.refClass(EBeansHolder.java:160)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.processing.EBeansHolder$Classes.<init>(EBeansHolder.java:50)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.processing.EBeansHolder.<init>(EBeansHolder.java:136)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.processing.ModelProcessor.process(ModelProcessor.java:40)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:472)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.processThrowing(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:343)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.process(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:318)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:556)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:701)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:987)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess0(JavacCompiler.java:559)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:534)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:168)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) /Users/vitaliyzasadnyy/Development/repository/androidcontainer/native-container-android/native-container-framework/src/main/java/com/nravo/framework/activity/MainScreenActivity.java:[44,-1] Unexpected error. Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.internal.codemodel.JCodeModel.ref(JCodeModel.java:372)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.processing.EBeansHolder.refClass(EBeansHolder.java:160)
```

Does anybody faced with this problem?

Comment: _"Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content:"_...

Comment: [Created issue](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/374)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Piwai suggestion I've solved this problem by moving to snapshot builds of android annotations. In order to switch to snapshots replace in your pom.xml current AA dependencies with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidannotations-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

also you'll need to add snapshot repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repository</id>
        <name>Sonatype oss snapshot repo</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**NOTE:** from AA v.2.7 release notes:

> the API jar is now a separate artifact, androidannotations-api. We do not use the api classifier any more.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the [issue you created](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/374), this is Maven / CodeModel bug in which `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` returns null for a reason I don't know. I'm about to release AndroidAnnotations 2.7, and this problem should not appear anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this. One solution was to add this to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```